# Today vs. same day last 3 weeks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, google-bigquery

I have data like in the below example, each cell is number of events.

```
| 29/09/2016 | 06/10/2016 | 13/10/2016 | Today | Hour |
|------------|------------|------------|-------|------|
| 470        | 649        | 652        | 140   | 0    |
| 159        | 322        | 354        | 925   | 1    |
| 874        | 399        | 412        | 168   | 2    |
| 699        | 312        | 69         | 51    | 3    |
| 911        | 908        | 780        | 322   | 4    |
| 756        | 805        | 579        | 161   | 5    |
| 653        | 295        | 900        | 885   | 6    |
| 637        | 699        | 221        | 310   | 7    |
| 227        | 508        | 382        | 655   | 8    |
| 823        | 782        | 437        | 278   | 9    |
| 389        | 34         | 95         | 754   | 10   |
| 229        | 309        | 29         | 945   | 11   |
| 163        | 16         | 593        | 968   | 12   |
| 833        | 953        | 767        | 438   | 13   |
| 153        | 356        | 619        | 741   | 14   |
| 335        | 493        | 511        | 877   | 15   |
| 469        | 353        | 643        | 431   | 16   |
| 610        | 137        | 121        | 647   | 17   |
| 411        | 951        | 674        | 57    | 18   |
| 593        | 854        | 500        | 380   | 19   |
| 16         | 608        | 445        | 889   | 20   |
| 764        | 143        | 734        | 178   | 21   |
| 709        | 845        | 297        | 292   | 22   |
| 894        | 355        | 309        | 98    | 23   |
```

I need to compare, per hour, number of events of today vs avg last 3 week same day - same hour vs. std vs Avg+ std vs Avg-std.

```
| Today-Std | Today+Std | Std | Average | Today | Hour |
|-----------|-----------|-----|---------|-------|------|
| -127      | 407       | 267 | 590     | 140   | 0    |
| 654       | 1196      | 271 | 278     | 925   | 1    |
| -105      | 441       | 273 | 562     | 168   | 2    |
| -224      | 326       | 275 | 360     | 51    | 3    |
| 49        | 595       | 273 | 866     | 322   | 4    |
| -106      | 428       | 267 | 713     | 161   | 5    |
| 617       | 1153      | 268 | 616     | 885   | 6    |
| 43        | 577       | 267 | 519     | 310   | 7    |
| 385       | 925       | 270 | 372     | 655   | 8    |
| 2         | 554       | 276 | 681     | 278   | 9    |
| 478       | 1030      | 276 | 173     | 754   | 10   |
| 674       | 1216      | 271 | 189     | 945   | 11   |
| 702       | 1234      | 266 | 257     | 968   | 12   |
| 182       | 694       | 256 | 851     | 438   | 13   |
| 496       | 986       | 245 | 376     | 741   | 14   |
| 630       | 1124      | 247 | 446     | 877   | 15   |
| 172       | 690       | 259 | 488     | 431   | 16   |
| 374       | 920       | 273 | 289     | 647   | 17   |
| -204      | 318       | 261 | 679     | 57    | 18   |
| 118       | 642       | 262 | 649     | 380   | 19   |
| 613       | 1165      | 276 | 356     | 889   | 20   |
| -88       | 444       | 266 | 547     | 178   | 21   |
| 37        | 547       | 255 | 617     | 292   | 22   |
| -168      | 364       | 266 | 519     | 98    | 23   |
```

Finally i need to create graph Today vs. Avg vs. Avg+STD vs. Avg-Std.

Need help to do this in Google Bigquery or SQL server 2012

Thanks

Comment: please clarify - which fields you include for Std calculation?

Comment: 29/09/2016, 06/10/2016 and 13/10/2016.

Comment: Can you show how you got 267 for example, for hour=0.somehow I am getting different number, so I am not sure of how exactly you calculated std in your example

Comment: Sorry, its just example of my data, random number. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Below is for BigQuery Legacy SQL.

It is too simple I think, so I am not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT
  Today - Std AS Std_Today,
  Today + Std AS Today_Std,
  Std,
  Average,
  Today,
  HOUR
FROM (
  SELECT
    INTEGER(ROUND(SQRT(((d1-Average)*(d1-Average) + (d2-Average)*(d2-Average) + (d3-Average)*(d3-Average))/2))) AS Std, 
    Average , Today, HOUR
  FROM (
    SELECT
      d1, d2, d3, Today, HOUR, INTEGER(ROUND((d1+d2+d3)/3)) AS Average
    FROM (
      SELECT d1, d2, d3, Today, HOUR FROM 
      (SELECT 470 AS d1, 649 AS d2, 652 AS d3, 140 AS Today, 0 AS HOUR),(SELECT 159 AS d1, 322 AS d2, 354 AS d3, 925 AS Today, 1 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 874 AS d1, 399 AS d2, 412 AS d3, 168 AS Today, 2 AS HOUR),(SELECT 699 AS d1, 312 AS d2, 69 AS d3, 51 AS Today, 3 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 911 AS d1, 908 AS d2, 780 AS d3, 322 AS Today, 4 AS HOUR),(SELECT 756 AS d1, 805 AS d2, 579 AS d3, 161 AS Today, 5 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 653 AS d1, 295 AS d2, 900 AS d3, 885 AS Today, 6 AS HOUR),(SELECT 637 AS d1, 699 AS d2, 221 AS d3, 310 AS Today, 7 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 227 AS d1, 508 AS d2, 382 AS d3, 655 AS Today, 8 AS HOUR),(SELECT 823 AS d1, 782 AS d2, 437 AS d3, 278 AS Today, 9 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 389 AS d1, 34 AS d2, 95 AS d3, 754 AS Today, 10 AS HOUR),(SELECT 229 AS d1, 309 AS d2, 29 AS d3, 945 AS Today, 11 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 163 AS d1, 16 AS d2, 593 AS d3, 968 AS Today, 12 AS HOUR),(SELECT 833 AS d1, 953 AS d2, 767 AS d3, 438 AS Today, 13 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 153 AS d1, 356 AS d2, 619 AS d3, 741 AS Today, 14 AS HOUR),(SELECT 335 AS d1, 493 AS d2, 511 AS d3, 877 AS Today, 15 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 469 AS d1, 353 AS d2, 643 AS d3, 431 AS Today, 16 AS HOUR),(SELECT 610 AS d1, 137 AS d2, 121 AS d3, 647 AS Today, 17 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 411 AS d1, 951 AS d2, 674 AS d3, 57 AS Today, 18 AS HOUR),(SELECT 593 AS d1, 854 AS d2, 500 AS d3, 380 AS Today, 19 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 16 AS d1, 608 AS d2, 445 AS d3, 889 AS Today, 20 AS HOUR),(SELECT 764 AS d1, 143 AS d2, 734 AS d3, 178 AS Today, 21 AS HOUR),
      (SELECT 709 AS d1, 845 AS d2, 297 AS d3, 292 AS Today, 22 AS HOUR),(SELECT 894 AS d1, 355 AS d2, 309 AS d3, 98 AS Today, 23 AS HOUR)
    ) as YourTable
  )
)
```

Can be easily modified (if needed) to BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql))

> From the other hand ...

you can use more elegant code in BigQuery Standard SQL

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 470 AS d1, 649 AS d2, 652 AS d3, 140 AS Today, 0 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 159 AS d1, 322 AS d2, 354 AS d3, 925 AS Today, 1 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 874 AS d1, 399 AS d2, 412 AS d3, 168 AS Today, 2 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 699 AS d1, 312 AS d2, 69 AS d3, 51 AS Today, 3 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 911 AS d1, 908 AS d2, 780 AS d3, 322 AS Today, 4 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 756 AS d1, 805 AS d2, 579 AS d3, 161 AS Today, 5 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 653 AS d1, 295 AS d2, 900 AS d3, 885 AS Today, 6 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 637 AS d1, 699 AS d2, 221 AS d3, 310 AS Today, 7 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 227 AS d1, 508 AS d2, 382 AS d3, 655 AS Today, 8 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 823 AS d1, 782 AS d2, 437 AS d3, 278 AS Today, 9 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 389 AS d1, 34 AS d2, 95 AS d3, 754 AS Today, 10 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 229 AS d1, 309 AS d2, 29 AS d3, 945 AS Today, 11 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 163 AS d1, 16 AS d2, 593 AS d3, 968 AS Today, 12 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 833 AS d1, 953 AS d2, 767 AS d3, 438 AS Today, 13 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 153 AS d1, 356 AS d2, 619 AS d3, 741 AS Today, 14 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 335 AS d1, 493 AS d2, 511 AS d3, 877 AS Today, 15 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 469 AS d1, 353 AS d2, 643 AS d3, 431 AS Today, 16 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 610 AS d1, 137 AS d2, 121 AS d3, 647 AS Today, 17 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 411 AS d1, 951 AS d2, 674 AS d3, 57 AS Today, 18 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 593 AS d1, 854 AS d2, 500 AS d3, 380 AS Today, 19 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 16 AS d1, 608 AS d2, 445 AS d3, 889 AS Today, 20 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 764 AS d1, 143 AS d2, 734 AS d3, 178 AS Today, 21 AS Hour UNION ALL
  SELECT 709 AS d1, 845 AS d2, 297 AS d3, 292 AS Today, 22 AS Hour UNION ALL SELECT 894 AS d1, 355 AS d2, 309 AS d3, 98 AS Today, 23 AS Hour 
),
tempTable AS (
  SELECT 
    (SELECT CAST(STDdev(d) AS INT64) FROM UNNEST([d1, d2, d3]) AS d) AS Std,
    (SELECT CAST(AVG(d) AS INT64) FROM UNNEST([d1, d2, d3]) AS d) AS Average
    , Today, Hour
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT 
  Today - Std AS Std_Today,
  Today + Std AS Today_Std,
  Std,
  Average,
  Today,
  Hour
FROM tempTable
ORDER BY Hour
```

> Which (funny enough) ...

leads me back to Legacy SQL version (but similar to above for Standard one)

```
SELECT
  Today - Std AS Std_Today,
  Today + Std AS Today_Std,
  Std,
  Average,
  Today,
  HOUR
FROM (
  SELECT
      INTEGER(STDDEV(d)) AS Std,
      INTEGER(AVG(d)) AS Average,
      Today, HOUR
  FROM (
    SELECT Today, HOUR, SPLIT(CONCAT(STRING(d1), ",", STRING(d2),  ",", STRING(d3))) AS d
    FROM (
      SELECT d1, d2, d3, Today, HOUR FROM 
        (SELECT 470 AS d1, 649 AS d2, 652 AS d3, 140 AS Today, 0 AS HOUR),(SELECT 159 AS d1, 322 AS d2, 354 AS d3, 925 AS Today, 1 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 874 AS d1, 399 AS d2, 412 AS d3, 168 AS Today, 2 AS HOUR),(SELECT 699 AS d1, 312 AS d2, 69 AS d3, 51 AS Today, 3 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 911 AS d1, 908 AS d2, 780 AS d3, 322 AS Today, 4 AS HOUR),(SELECT 756 AS d1, 805 AS d2, 579 AS d3, 161 AS Today, 5 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 653 AS d1, 295 AS d2, 900 AS d3, 885 AS Today, 6 AS HOUR),(SELECT 637 AS d1, 699 AS d2, 221 AS d3, 310 AS Today, 7 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 227 AS d1, 508 AS d2, 382 AS d3, 655 AS Today, 8 AS HOUR),(SELECT 823 AS d1, 782 AS d2, 437 AS d3, 278 AS Today, 9 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 389 AS d1, 34 AS d2, 95 AS d3, 754 AS Today, 10 AS HOUR),(SELECT 229 AS d1, 309 AS d2, 29 AS d3, 945 AS Today, 11 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 163 AS d1, 16 AS d2, 593 AS d3, 968 AS Today, 12 AS HOUR),(SELECT 833 AS d1, 953 AS d2, 767 AS d3, 438 AS Today, 13 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 153 AS d1, 356 AS d2, 619 AS d3, 741 AS Today, 14 AS HOUR),(SELECT 335 AS d1, 493 AS d2, 511 AS d3, 877 AS Today, 15 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 469 AS d1, 353 AS d2, 643 AS d3, 431 AS Today, 16 AS HOUR),(SELECT 610 AS d1, 137 AS d2, 121 AS d3, 647 AS Today, 17 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 411 AS d1, 951 AS d2, 674 AS d3, 57 AS Today, 18 AS HOUR),(SELECT 593 AS d1, 854 AS d2, 500 AS d3, 380 AS Today, 19 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 16 AS d1, 608 AS d2, 445 AS d3, 889 AS Today, 20 AS HOUR),(SELECT 764 AS d1, 143 AS d2, 734 AS d3, 178 AS Today, 21 AS HOUR),
        (SELECT 709 AS d1, 845 AS d2, 297 AS d3, 292 AS Today, 22 AS HOUR),(SELECT 894 AS d1, 355 AS d2, 309 AS d3, 98 AS Today, 23 AS HOUR)
    ) AS YourTable
  )
  GROUP BY Today, HOUR
)
```

Comment: Thanks but i don't know how to extract data like in my example.

Comment: that's nice to hear! where is your data exactly? isn't it in BigQuery in some table?

Comment: I have table with events per day/ hour. i want to compare day with the same day from pervius month.

Comment: what is exactly the schema of your table?! it sounds like what you provided in question is not what you have  - please update it! so i will try to adopt above to your real data!

Comment: event Hour Date
564 0 29/09/2016
469 0 06/10/2016
123 0 13/10/2016
567 0 21/10/2016
363 1 29/09/2016
683 1 06/10/2016
674 1 13/10/2016
435 1 21/10/2016

Comment: @ariel - it appears you provided totally different table schema in your original question :o( this answer is already lengthy enough - so I will post new answer to address your changes

Answer (score 1):

below is to address comments on my original answer - it happened that data schema in original question was incorrect but rather is as below:

```
events  hour    date     
649     0   06/10/2016   
652     0   13/10/2016   
140     0   20/10/2016   
470     0   29/09/2016   
322     1   06/10/2016   
354     1   13/10/2016   
925     1   20/10/2016   
159     1   29/09/2016   
399     2   06/10/2016
```

So assuming dates are stored as strings with "dd/mm/yyyy" format  - below is the query for BigQuery Standard SQL (see [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql) and [Migrating from legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/migrating-from-legacy-sql))

```
SELECT 
  Date, Hour, Events, Average, Std,
  events - Std AS Std_Events,
  events + Std AS Events_Std
FROM (
  SELECT 
    x.DATE, x.hour, x.events, 
    CAST(STDDEV(z.events) AS INT64) AS Std,
    CAST(AVG(z.events) AS INT64) Average
  FROM yourTable AS x
  JOIN (SELECT '20/10/2016' AS xDay) AS y  -- use this line to set specific day to treat as today
  --JOIN (SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)) AS xDay) AS y  -- use this line to do analysis for yesterday 
  ON x.date = xDay
  JOIN yourTable as z
  ON MOD(DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', xDay), PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', z.Date), DAY), 7) = 0
  AND DIV(DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', xDay), PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', z.Date), DAY), 7) BETWEEN 1 AND 3
  AND z.hour = x.hour
  GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
)
ORDER BY hour
```

You can transform

```
  JOIN (SELECT '20/10/2016' AS xDay) AS y
```

to have few dates that you need to analyse in one run - for example

```
  JOIN (SELECT '19/10/2016' AS xDay UNION ALL
        SELECT '20/10/2016' AS xDay) AS y
```